# Nested documents in Solr using spring data solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am trying to use Solr (solr-6.5.1) for storing xml files and need to figure out how to insert it as nested documents using spring data solr (2.1.3). Till now I was not able to find a working example on how to do that.

I read [Yonik's post](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) on nested documents, but still couldn't figure out how to do that with spring data solr. I implemented some java objects which should represent the data and thus inserted as child documents, but Solr seems to interpret them as flattened **Strings**.

If someone has a working example on how to put nested documents with 2-3 child documents, I would be very glad if you could share this.